# what is difference between text, customdata and meta in hovertemplate in plotly?

Tags: plotly-python

I am trying to customize hovertemplate. I found there are 3 things I can use to add custom data, which is text,customdata and meta. I can use these 3 in the below example. I am not sure what are their difference?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = [1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [2.02825,1.63728,6.83839,4.8485,4.73463],
    text = ['tx1','tx2','tx3','tx4','tx5'],
    customdata=['cd1','cd2','cd3','cd4','cd5'],
    meta=['mta1','mta2','mta3','mta4','mta5'],
    hovertemplate =
    '<i>Price</i>: $%{y:.2f}'+
    '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}'+
    '<br><b>%{text}</b>'+
    '<br><b>%{customdata}</b>'+
    '<b>%{meta}</b>',
    showlegend = False))

fig.update_layout(
    hoverlabel_align = 'right',
    title = "Set hover text with hovertemplate")

fig.show()
```

Also for customdata, can I use 2 dimensions so I can use customdata[0],customdata[1]? I tried and it didn't work. Anyway, I just don't understand how it works.

Thanks for your help.